# Visual (non-HTML) display of post revisions

Tags: posts, revisions

So you know when you click "show revisions" on a post and can choose to edit any of the recent drafts?
I have a client, non tech-savvy, who is frustrated by how the revision previews display as HTML rather than how they would appear on the site.  He finds it hard to determine which revision he wants to use because he can't see the images, formatting, etc.  I looked for a plugin that would allow you to preview the revisions in their published form, but was unable to find anything of the kind.  Can anyone suggest a plugin or a solution to this issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Revisionary](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/revisionary/) let's you preview the revisions. But it also adds other functionality (Pending revisions), so maybe not the best solution.